# Horrible sound quality/dropouts over Bluetooth with USB receiver?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I'm getting really horrible results when trying to play back audio from my computer to my new Motorola S305 headphones. I currently have a knock-off USB Bluetooth adapter which isn't exactly the best quality in the world. Should I get a new adapter, and if so, which one should I invest in which works well with Ubuntu? I'd also like it to have Bluetooth 3.0, has this been implemented yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A €9.00 adapter that I use all the time with my Belkin Bluetooth receiver. So I'm able to send a sound stream to my speakers. Works great really, I never had a disconnect or any sound-loss.